# Sencha Touch 2.4.2 Button Function not working

Tags: javascript, extjs, sencha-touch-2

I have a toolbar with 4 buttons. **'Approval'**, **'New Request Patient'**, **'View Request Details'**, and **'Close'** buttons. By default when the page loads, all of these buttons are visible **EXCEPT** for the **'Approval'** button. I want the 'Approval' button to be **visible** when the user clicked on the **'New Request Patient'** which will take the user to that page. And the button will be **hidden** again when the user clicked on the **'View Request Details'** button. So that is my first problem.

My second problem is when the user clicked on the **'New Request Patient'** button, the **'View Request Details'** button will **change its text** to **'View Request List'**. For some reason I can't figure this out. Here is my code: -

```
{
                xtype: 'toolbar',
                docked: 'bottom',
                layout: {
                    pack: 'left',
                    size: '20px'
                },
                defaults: {
                    margin: '10 10'
                },
                items: [
                    {
                        xtype: 'button',
                        text: 'Approval',
                        hidden: true
                    },
                    {
                        xtype: 'button',
                        text: 'New Request Patient',
                        handler: function () {
                            Ext.getCmp('requestpatient').setActiveItem(1);
                        },

                        //listeners: {
                        //    tap: function()
                        //    {
                        //        myButton.setText('View Request List');
                        //    }
                        //}
                    },
                    {
                        xtype: 'button',
                        id: 'myButton',
                        text: 'View Request Details',
                        handler: function () {
                            Ext.getCmp('requestpatient').setActiveItem(0);
                        }

                    },
                    {
                        xtype: 'button',
                        text: 'Close'
                    },
                ]
            },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this (see below), but Im not sure I understand what you mean by your button text gets changed? I see a commented code there, to do exactly that.

```
items: [{
    xtype: 'button',
    text: 'Approval',
    hidden: true
},{
    xtype: 'button',
    text: 'New Request Patient',
    handler: function (b) {
         Ext.getCmp('requestpatient').setActiveItem(1);
         b.up().down('button[text=Approval]').setHidden(false);
    },

},{
    xtype: 'button',
    itemId: 'myButton',
    text: 'View Request Details',
    handler: function (b) {
        Ext.getCmp('requestpatient').setActiveItem(0);
        b.up().down('button[text=Approval]').setHidden(true);
    }

},{
    xtype: 'button',
    text: 'Close'
}]
```

Comment: Thank you so much. That works fine =)
what I mean by the text of the button changed is that, by default it is set to 'View Request Details' which will take the user to view details page. So, I want to make the button says 'View Request List' when at the View Request Details page, so the user knows if they clicked the button it will take them back to the request list page. Do I use the setText? And how can I do it. Thank you

Comment: Never mind, I figure it out by tweaking your code a bit. Thank you so much for the help though :)